# Cant update table in using isset

Tags: post, isset

I have a table called settings, when I would change or enter data into the form it did not change the data in the table. In addition on form an image upload file is not running, There may be the wrong code below.

(Solved by me)

Maybe someone can help me Related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing here is tottaly in secure and your data can be hacked / manipulate really fast.
Why dont you use a framework like codeignighter there are about 100 easy frameworks that will  help you manage database a lot easyer.

Are you sure that you are updating the wrond ID? `where id = 1`, seems to be not dynamic.

Please post your error http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_error.asp

I know it is not so related to your question, but you should see these light frameworks:

```
http://kohanaframework.org/
https://github.com/ElbertF/Swiftlet
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter
```

Comment: I know this is very dangerous, but I've tired to find fault with this

Comment: I stronly recomend using light framework, youll make your life ezyer

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking the return status of of your query, so if it's not working you wouldn't know. Do this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET site='$name',keywords='$keys',descrp='$desc',email='$email',fbpage='$fbpage',twitter='$twitter',gplus='$gplus',disclaimer='$disclaimer',template='$template' WHERE id=1")
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Note: `mysql_*()` is deprecated: you shouldn't use it. Use `mysqli_*()` or `PDO` instead.

Also: You are susceptible to an SQL Injection attack. You should escape your input variables with `mysql_real_escape_string()` (or the equivalent if you switch to `mysqli`), or consider moving to prepared statements.